# Android selector not working

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I have made three different images for a next button in my activity. A focused image, normal image and an image when the button is not enabled.

However, I wanted to test it and see how ot looks when it's not been enabled.

So on start I set it to false and it does work, I cannot touch it and it does not change to focused anymore, but the image does not change.

The `ImageButton` from my layout.

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/nextbutton" />
```

The selector file **nextbutton.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next_focused" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

What is wrong? It'll only change to focused and normal state but never to the disabled one. (I just noticed that it might be the wrong word for it...).

Answer (score 1):

I found it out. I still don't know for sure why but I have a clue. I had to this line to every other item in the selector.

```
android:state_enabled="false"
```

So it looks like this :

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next_focused" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_next" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="false" />
```

Comment: Great tip, solved my issue. After all its quite simple: Android searches for a matching selector from top to bottom. First one (the default with no states defined) always matches and is always used...